# Как указывать пути к локальным репозитариям в Mercurial HG в файле hgrc

Tags: git, repository, mercurial, msys2, tortoise-hg

На локальной машине у меня хранится локальный репозиторий `C:\repo\my_proj`

Необходимо сделать настроить `TortoiseHG Workbanch` для получения файлов репозитория.

При указании настроек в файле `<work_place>\.hg\hgrc`

```
[paths]
C:\repo\my_proj
```

Программа выдаёт ошибку:

> No valid default remote repositary URL or path has been configured for this repository.
>
> Please type and save a remote repository path on the Sync widget

Но когда я делаю тоже самое в ручную через консоль GIT-BASH то всё работает

`hg pull /c/repo/my_proj/`

Однако я не могу использовать не это и не тот синтаксис в файле конфигурации.

Подскажите правильный синтаксис для указания путей к локальному репозиторию для `hgrc`?

**Сборка софта:**

Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.9)

Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу. Для путей в ОС Windows стоит использовать примерно такой синтаксис:

```bsh
[paths]
file:///c:/repo/my_proj/
```

или

```bsh
[paths]
repo = file:///c:/repo/my_proj/
```